# After submit form I want to stay in the same page and display :notice messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

All my code is working nicely, I want to render the same page :new after a user submits a form with your order. The problem is about the :notice message that I want to display `Pedido enviado com sucesso.` in the page after a submission but it doesn't work. My validation error messages are displayed nicely but I don't know why my success message doesn't.

Any tips?

(Sorry about my code indentation)

My `pedidos_controller` goes down:

```
class PedidosController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @pedido = Pedido.new
    1.times do
      pessoa = @pedido.build_pessoa
      produto = @pedido.produtos.build
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @pedido }
  end
end

def create
  @pedido = Pedido.new(params[:pedido])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @pedido.save
      PedidosMailer.delay.registro_do_pedido(@pedido)
      PedidosMailer.delay.email_para_cotar_produtos(@pedido)
      format.html { redirect_to action: "new", notice: 'Pedido enviado com sucesso.' }
      format.json { render json: @pedido, status: :created, location: @pedido }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @pedido.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
end
```

my `new.html.erb` view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

my `_form.html.erb` view:

```
<%= form_for(@pedido, :html => { :class => "form-contato"}) do |f| %>
<% if @pedido.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>Ocorreram <%= pluralize(@pedido.errors.count, "erro") %></h2>

  <ul>
  <% @pedido.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    <h1>Dados pessoais</h1>
    <%= f.fields_for :pessoa do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'pessoa_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

<div class="span8">
  <h1>Ítens</h1>

  <%= f.fields_for :produtos do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'produto_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="span10">
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Adicionar mais produtos", f, :produtos %>
</div>
  <%= button_tag "Enviar", class: "btn btn-red span10", name: "commit" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

my `_pessoa_fields.html.erb` view:

```
<fieldset>
<%= f.text_field :nome, class: "span4", placeholder: "Nome" %>
<br />
<%= f.text_field :telefone, class: "span4", placeholder: "Telefone" %>
<br />
<%= f.text_field :email, class: "span4", placeholder: "Email" %>
</fieldset>
```

my `_produto_fields.html.erb` view:

```
<% @lista_de_produtos = ["Qualibom standard", "Qualibom premium", "Bomdemais standard", "Bomdemais premium"] %>
<fieldset class="campos-produtos span10">
<div class="span3">
    <%= f.select :nome, options_for_select(@lista_de_produtos, :selected => f.object.nome), :prompt => 'Selecione um produto' %>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <%= f.text_field :quantidade, class: "span3", placeholder: "Quantidade" %>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `1.times do`....?

Comment: It's a little mistake, before I showed 2 or 3 fields of products to user. Thanks to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `flash[:notice]`, not `notice`, in your view:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
```

When you pass a message via the `notice:` parameter of `redirect_to`, it's placed into the `flash` array, which is a special pseduo-session which persist for a single request:

From the [ActionController::Redirecting documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html):

> It is also possible to assign a flash message as part of the redirection. There are two special accessors for the commonly used flash names alert and notice as well as a general purpose flash bucket.